# How do I fix this error "TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not callable" in openerp 7 webkit report?

Tags: odoo, mako

I've tried everything I know with the amount_to_text function in a webkit report but I'm simply getting nowhere. I've looked at the check writing module and duplicated it as much as I can but still no results. I'm using webkit instead of rml and I'm not sure if this makes a difference in v7 because the same code works fine in 6.1. Any help would be hugely appreciated

This is the code from the .py file:

```
import time
from report import report_sxw
from osv import osv     
from openerp.osv import osv,fields
from openerp.tools.translate import _
from openerp.tools.amount_to_text_en import amount_to_text

class tax_receipt(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(tax_receipt, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'cr':cr,
            'uid': uid,
            'amount_to_text': amount_to_text,
        })

report_sxw.report_sxw('report.tax.receipt',
                       'account.bank.statement.line', 
                       'addons/account_financial_report_webkit/report/webkit_html_bank_statement.mako',
                       parser=tax_receipt)

# vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

The excerpt from the mako file looks like this:

```
<table width="95%" cellpadding="5px" cellpadding="5px">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="text-align:left;border-bottom:1px solid;">
        <td width="10%">The sum of </td>
        <td width="80%" style="text-align:left;border-bottom:1px solid;">**${ amount_to_text(inv.amount) }**</td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

when I try to generate the report, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0\Server\server\openerp\addons\report_webkit\webkit_report.py", line 266, in create_single_pdf

File "mako\template.pyc", line 302, in render

File "mako\runtime.pyc", line 660, in _render

File "mako\runtime.pyc", line 692, in _render_context

File "mako\runtime.pyc", line 718, in _exec_template

File "memory:0x4a2d6d0", line 78, in render_body
<td width="80%" style="text-align:left;border-bottom:1px solid;">${ amount_to_text(inv.amount) }</td>
TypeError: 'Undefined' object is not callable
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your .py parser is imported properly in your module, that is in **init**.py

```
### __init__.py file###

import your_parser
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where u have the function defenition for amount_to_text function. In openerp 7 it has to specified in this way.

```
class tax_receipt(report_sxw.rml_parse):
    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(tax_receipt, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'cr':cr,
            'uid': uid,
            'amount_to_text': self._amount_to_text,
        })
def _amount_to_text(self):
        res_users_obj = pooler.get_pool(self.cr.dbname).get('res.users')
        company_vat = res_users_obj.browse(self.cr, self.uid, self.uid).company_id.partner_id.vat
        return company_vat
```

And in report you've to use this

```
<table width="95%" cellpadding="5px" cellpadding="5px">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="text-align:left;border-bottom:1px solid;">
        <td width="10%">The sum of </td>
        <td width="80%" style="text-align:left;border-bottom:1px solid;">${amount_to_text(inv.amount)} </td>
      </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

To Store in a variable you've to use

```
<% res_text = amount_to_text(inv.amount) %>
```

And to Print

```
${res_text}
```

Look at the sale_order_webkit module for sample. And revert back for clarifications. Good Luck!!